Usable cloud client for Linux
I need a free cloud service (such as Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.) with a natively-supported client for Rocky Linux and Ubuntu Linux.
(A nice-to-have would be to also offer a Windows client, but basically all cloud services already offer that.)
So far, all cloud services I've found have just a Windows or MacOS client; using Linux with the service, while theoretically possible, is not officially supported, is not user-friendly, and requires a lot of time-consuming work -- installing other software, scripting, compiling, tweaking, debugging, and so on.

MEGA is proud of being Linux-friendly and offers a wide variety of solutions for Linux users.

Firstly, there is the desktop app that fully integrates with most Linux environments.
https://help.mega.io/ru/installs-apps/desktop/linux
Secondly, there are also plugins for all major file managers (Nautilus, Nemo, Dolphin, Thunar).
And thirdly, there is also a rich featured bash-like shell prompt MEGA CMD.
https://help.mega.io/ru/installs-apps/command-line/cmd

MEGA CMD (Command Line) is the official headless MEGA software. It supports all MEGA features using commands rather than a graphical user interface (GUI). This is useful for accessing your account from within a script, or interactively in environments that do not offer a GUI, such as a remote server.
There are unofficial python clients for chomikuj.pl, but they seem abandoned.
https://github.com/Grycek/ChomikDownloader
https://github.com/Grycek/ChomikUploader
I'll also note.
https://github.com/dutchcoders/transfer.sh
Easy and fast file sharing from the command-line. This code contains the server with everything you need to create your own instance.
Transfer.sh currently supports the s3 (Amazon S3), gdrive (Google Drive), storj (Storj) providers, and local file system (local).
